# registro con 2 rutas en un boton ajax Laravel 5.8

Tags: jquery, laravel, eloquent, controller

Tengo un problema con mi registro, estoy intentando capturar el id_alumno que acabo de registrar, pero el problema es que estoy enviando mi registro alumno + registro de un horario, por lo que se realizan al mismo tiempo y no logro capturar el id del alumno registrado.
Las clases del horario tienen que tener el id del alumno al cual le estoy asignando dicho horario.

el alumno se envía mediante un formulario post con su respectiva ruta y el horario lo envió mediante ajax e igualmente con su respectiva ruta.
Al momento de enviar el ajax activo el submit del formulario alumno para que al apretar el botón "Guardar" se envié el submit y el json del horario

Este es mi formulario de alumno

```
<form id="alumno-frm" name="alumno-frm" class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('alumno.store') }}"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Este es el ajax en el cual envió el json que obtengo desde el fnGetData de mi datatable horario y activo el submit de alumno

```
$.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'json',
  data: JSON.stringify(p),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success : function(){
    $('#alumno-frm').submit(); // ENVIO FORMULARIO DE ALUMNO MEDIANTE SU RUTA
  },
  error: function(){
    Toast.fire({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'Ha ocurrido un problema con el registro de horario práctico'
    });
  }
});
```

Esta es la función de alumno en el controlador

```
public function store(Request $request){ // STORE
  $alumno = alumnoModel::updateOrCreate(['id_alumno' => $request->id_alumno],
      [
          'rut' => $request->rut,
          'nombre' => $request->nombre,
          'apellidos' => $request->apellidos,
          'correo' => $request->correo,
          'clave' => $request->clave,
          'telefono' => $request->telefono,
          'id_curso' => $request->curso,
          'id_licencia' => $request->licencia
      ]
  );
  $message= array(
      'message' => 'Alumno ha sido agregado con exito',
      'type' => 'success'
  );
  return redirect()->back()->with($message);
}
```

y esta es la función del horario en el cual se ve que intente hacerlo obteniendo el ultimo registro y sumándole 1, pero el problema es que al no tener registros posteriores me da error y se que esta mal hacerlo de esa forma.

```
public function storeHorario(Request $request){ // GUARDAR HORARIO

  $id_alumno = alumnoModel::orderby('id_alumno','desc')->select('id_alumno')->first(); // intento 1

  $data = json_decode($request->getContent());

  foreach($data as $array_data) {
    $dato2 = $array_data['0'];
    $dato3 = $array_data['1'];
    $dato4 = $array_data['2'];
    $dato5 = 'practica';
    $dato6 = $array_data['3'];
    $dato7 = $array_data['7'];
    $dato8 = $array_data['8'];
    $dato9 = $array_data['9'];
    $dato10 = $array_data['10'];

    horarioModel::updateOrCreate(
      ['id_horario' => $dato9?: NULL],
      [
         'clase' => $dato2,
         'fecha' => $dato3,
         'hora' => $dato4,
         'tipo' => $dato5,
         'minutos_bloque' => $dato6,
         'id_profesor' => $dato7,
         'id_vehiculo' => $dato8,
         'id_curso' => $dato10,
         'id_alumno' => $id_alumno->id_alumno+1 // sumo 1 al ultimo registro de alumno
      ]
    );
  }
  return json_encode($data);
}
```

Se me había ocurrido algo como un timeout para esperar a que primero se registre el alumno y luego se ejecute la función de horario para capturar el ultimo id_alumno registro, pero busque y no encontré nada parecido.

de antemano agradezco la ayuda.

**Edicion**

```
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Confirmacion!',
  text: "Se creara el alumno y se le asignara al curso seleccionado",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#28A645',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Si, registrar alumno',
  cancelButtonText: 'No, volver'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
      // captura el evento submit del formulario y previene su acción por defecto
    $('#alumno-frm').on('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // crea un array con los datos del formulario
      let form = document.forms["alumno-frm"];
      let fd = new FormData(form);
      let alumno = {};
      for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
          alumno[key] = prop;
      }
      // crea un array con los datos de la tabla
      let horarios = $("#tablaAgregados").dataTable().fnGetData();

      // agrega ambos a la data que envías con ajax, convirtiédolos a json
      $.ajax({
        url:"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", // reemplaza esta url por la ruta que corresponda para que llegue a la función store del Controlador
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
          alumno: alumno,
          horarios: horarios
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success : function(response){
          console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(response){
          console.log(response)
        }
      });
    });
  }
})
```

al presionar el btnCrear (guardar) se ejecuta el sweetAlert de confirmacion, una vez que le doy a "si" no hace nada
Por si acaso dejare un pastebin con el boton completo para que se entienda mejor (https://pastebin.com/iDhnyvmr), respecto a los controladores las 2 funciones (store y storeHorario) están exactamente como me las indico @porloscerros Ψ

***2da forma***
https://pastebin.com/GBdTiXES
Esta forma la hice mientras esperaba alguna respuesta, también funciona sin problemas, pero recomiendo utilizar la solución que dio @porloscerros Ψ

Comment: Por que tienes dos formularios?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ es un formulario y el otro es un fnGetData de un datatable, el cual envio por ajax, de echo tu me ayudaste en hacer eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algo que se me ocurre es que puedes enviar todos los datos, el del formulario del alumno y los datos de la tabla en la misma llamada.
Luego lo manejas en tu controlador para registrarlos en la BD.
Te dejo algunos comentarios en el código para que tengas la idea.

En tu jscript:

```
Swal.fire({
    title: 'Confirmacion!',
    text: "Se creara el alumno y se le asignara al curso seleccionado",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#28A645',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Si, registrar alumno',
    cancelButtonText: 'No, volver'
}).then((result) => {
    if (result.value) {
        // crea un objeto con los datos del formulario
        let form = document.forms["alumno-frm"];
        let fd = new FormData(form);
        let alumno = {};
        for (let [key, prop] of fd) {
            alumno[key] = prop;
        }
        // crea un array con los datos de la tabla
        let horarios = $("#tablaAgregados").dataTable().fnGetData();

        // agrega ambos a la data que envías con ajax, convirtiédolos a json
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('alumno.store') }}",
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                alumno: alumno,
                horarios: horarios
            }),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success : function(response){
                console.log(response)
            },
            error: function(response){
                console.log(response)
            }
        });
    }
})
```

En el controlador recibe los datos en la función pública donde registras el alumno y luego le pasas los datos de los horarios a la función que registra los datos de los horarios:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    // decodifica el json a una variable php
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    // asigna los datos correspondientes al formulario del alumno a una variable aparte
    $data_alumno = $data->alumno;
    // modifica o crea el registro a BD
    $alumno = alumnoModel::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id_alumno' => $data_alumno->id_alumno?: NULL
        ],
        [
            'rut' => $data_alumno->rut,
            'nombre' => $data_alumno->nombre,
            'apellidos' => $data_alumno->apellidos,
            'correo' => $data_alumno->correo,
            'clave' => $data_alumno->clave,
            'telefono' => $data_alumno->telefono,
            'id_curso' => $data_alumno->curso,
            'id_licencia' => $data_alumno->licencia
        ]
    );
    // envía los datos  de la tabla horarios a la función storeHorario para registrarlos en BD, nota que va también el dato del alumno reciín creado, que también lo necesitarás
    $this->storeHorario($alumno, $data->horarios);

    $message= array(
        'message' => 'Los datos se guardaron con exito',
        'type' => 'success'
    );
    return response()->json($message);
}

private function storeHorario($alumno, $data){
    // esto es practicamente lo mismo que tenía
    foreach($data as $array_data) {
        $dato2 = $array_data['0'];
        $dato3 = $array_data['1'];
        $dato4 = $array_data['2'];
        $dato5 = 'practica';
        $dato6 = $array_data['3'];
        $dato7 = $array_data['7'];
        $dato8 = $array_data['8'];
        $dato9 = $array_data['9'];
        $dato10 = $array_data['10'];

        horarioModel::updateOrCreate(
            [
                'id_horario' => $dato9?: NULL
            ],
            [
                'clase' => $dato2,
                'fecha' => $dato3,
                'hora' => $dato4,
                'tipo' => $dato5,
                'minutos_bloque' => $dato6,
                'id_profesor' => $dato7,
                'id_vehiculo' => $dato8,
                'id_curso' => $dato10,
                'id_alumno' => $alumno->id_alumno
            ]
        );
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101486/discussion-on-answer-by-porloscerros--registro-con-2-rutas-en-un-boton-ajax-lar).

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema parecido y la forma en la que lo solucioné fue obligando a las peticiones ajax que sean síncronas (tengo que reconocer que no siempre me ha funcionado hacer eso), pero quizás te pueda ayudar. Para hacer que las peticiones sean síncronas puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"{{ route('alumno.horario') }}",
  type: 'POST',
  dataType:'json',
  contentType: 'json',
  async: false,
  data: JSON.stringify(p),
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  success : function(){
    $('#alumno-frm').submit(); // ENVIO FORMULARIO DE ALUMNO MEDIANTE SU RUTA
  },
  error: function(){
    Toast.fire({
      type: 'error',
      title: 'Ha ocurrido un problema con el registro de horario práctico'
    });
  }
});
```

Ten cuidado utilizando estas peticiones síncronas, ya que podrían bloquearte la aplicación si no tienes cuidado, ya que una petición síncrona bloquea la aplicación hasta que finalice

Comment: Lo intente, pero no me funciono, intente colocando mi submit antes y después, pero no tuve éxito